# Android target: not installed and plugin installation failed Cordova

Tags: android, linux, cordova

I'm having issues with my Cordova installation : I installed cordova, Android Studio, Android SDK, Java and defined 
`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java"
ANDROID_HOME="/home/myusername/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-24"`

In `/etc/environment`. When I go to a Cordova project and type `cordova requirments android`, I have the error

> Android Studio project detected
>
> Requirements check results for android:
>   Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
>   Android SDK: installed true
>   Android target: not installed
>   android: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
>   Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle

When I change `ANDROID_HOME` to `/home/myusername/Android/Sdk/`, the error becomes

> avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1

I can't find the problem, I didn't found a good answer on the other posts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors:

- the android sdk is not found

I think this is because ANDROID_HOME should be more like `/home/myusername/Android/Sdk/`
(the root of the sdk so that the cordova android platform will be able to choose the sdk version)

- android command is not found in the path

you need to add to the PATH the folder where the android command is located. This should be `/home/myusername/Android/Sdk/tools`

Comment: I did all you said, it's better, the `android` command works well. Now I have still an error : the Android target is said not installed, and I have th enew error  `avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1`

Comment: Okay, I spoke à bit fast : all the requirements are satified, but when I run `cordova building android`, nothing is generated... Do toi know why ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try to change ANDROID_HOME to /home/myusername/Android/

Almost adding to PATH

> :$HOME/Android/tools:$HOME/Android/build-tools:$Home/Android/platform-tools:$PATH

Otherwise i have export the GRADLE_HOME too. 

 Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my error. I installed JAVA, but I didn't added it to the alternatives. The solution was to add my freshly installed JAVA version as main JAVA with `sudo update-alternatives --config java`